# To create a new bitcoin address cloned Bit-Wasp/bitcoin-php code

Tags: php

I am using code from [GitHub](https://github.com/Bit-Wasp/bitcoin-php).

Once I run composer its gives error as:

> C:\wamp64\www\bitcoin-php-master>composer require bitwasp/bitcoin
>   Using version v0.0.33.1 for bitwasp/bitcoin
>   ./composer.json has been updated
>   Loading composer repositories with package information
>   Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
>   Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1
    - The requested package bitwasp/bitcoin No version set (parsed as 1.0.0) is
satisfiable by bitwasp/bitcoin[No version set (parsed as 1.0.0)] but these confl
ict with your requirements or minimum-stability.

> Installation failed, reverting `./composer.json` to its original content.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Since [`Bit-Wasp/bitcoin-php`](https://github.com/Bit-Wasp/bitcoin-php) has its own [`composer.json` file](https://github.com/Bit-Wasp/bitcoin-php/blob/master/composer.json), after cloning you should just run:

```
composer install
```

If there is still some issue, run the following command to diagnose the problem:

```
composer self-update
composer diagnose
```

Otherwise [report it at the project page](https://github.com/Bit-Wasp/bitcoin-php/issues).

Answer (score 0):

You have to clear composer.json and try again.

Comment: Hi
Thank you for reply.
Not able to understand correctly about clear composer.json.
What exacts i have to do.